# Embedding Azure Data Explorer to SaaS app without AAD authentication

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I would like to use Azure Data Explorer (ADX) dashboards embedding feature for building analytics dashboards for our multi-tenant SaaS application.

At present, I am quite certain this is not possible. Dashboards seem to have their own access control and do not support AD App as principal. But throwing it out there to see if someone with real expertise on the subject matter can verify this.

Making this secure would additionally require implementing row level security on ADX.

Azure Dashboards embedding seems to be in preview currently. Since we do not use Azure AD for authentication of our users I would instead want to make AAD Application per SaaS application tenant.

It seems I am able to make a query with that AAD application in our backend like this:

```cs
           var clusterName = "<adx-cluster-name>";
           var dbName = "<adx-db-name>";
            var appId = "<AppId>";
            var appTenantId = "<tenantId>";
            var clientSecret = _configuration["ADX:ClientSecret"];

            var kcsb = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder($"https://{clusterName}.westeurope.kusto.windows.net/{dbName}")
                .WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(
                    appId,
                    clientSecret,
                    appTenantId);

            var queryString = @"
                ['events']
                    | where Name == 'Apply'
                    | summarize sum(ItemCount) by startofmonth(TimeGenerated), tostring(Properties['tenantId'])
            ";

            var ret = new List<string>();

            var client = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider(kcsb);
            var queryResult = client.ExecuteQuery($"{queryString}");

            while (queryResult.Read())
            {
                // Important note: For demonstration purposes we show how to read the data
                // using the "bare bones" IDataReader interface. In a production environment
                // one would normally use some ORM library to automatically map the data from
                // IDataReader into a strongly-typed record type (e.g. Dapper.Net, AutoMapper, etc.)

                DateTime time = queryResult.GetDateTime(0);
                string tenantId = queryResult.GetString(1);
                long itemCount = queryResult.GetInt64(2);
                var line = String.Format("{0}\t{1,-20}\t{2}", time, itemCount, tenantId);
                ret.Add(line);
            }
```

But acquiring a token like this:

```cs
           var clusterName = "<adx-cluster-name>";
           var dbName = "<adx-db-name>";
            var appId = "<AppId>";
            var appTenantId = "<tenantId>";
            var clientSecret = _configuration["ADX:ClientSecret"];
            // Get access token for the analytics by authenticating with Azure AD Application
            var kustoUri = $"https://{clusterName}.westeurope.kusto.windows.net";



            // Create a confidential authentication client for Azure AD:
            var authClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
                .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{appTenantId}")
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret) // can be replaced by .WithCertificate to authenticate with an X.509 certificate
                .Build();
            
            // Acquire aplpication token for Azure Data Explorer:
            var result = authClient.AcquireTokenForClient(
                    new[] { $"{kustoUri}/.default" } // Define scopes for accessing Azure Data Explorer cluster
                    //new[] { $"{kustoUri}/{dbName}/.default" } // Try to acess data in DB scope...
                ).ExecuteAsync().Result;

            // Extract Bearer access token 
            var bearerToken = result.AccessToken;
```

Basically trying to follow this application authentication example instead of on-behalf-of authentication:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/access-control/how-to-authenticate-with-aad#application-authentication

And using it in our react frontend to pass to iframe (as response to "getToken" event from iFrame) does not get us authenticated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/monaco/host-web-ux-in-iframe#embed-dashboards-preview

```js
const scope = event.data.scope === 'query' ? analyticsAuthQuery.data.adxLink + "/.default" : event.data.scope;
event.source?.postMessage({ type: "postToken", message: analyticsAuthQuery.data.adxToken, scope: scope });
```

iFrame is defined like this:

```
            <iframe title="Analytics Dashboard" className={styles.iframe}
              
              src="https://dataexplorer.azure.com/dashboards/?f-IFrameAuth=true&f-PersistAfterEachRun=false&f-Homepage=false&f-ShowPageHeader=false&f-ShowNavigation=false&f-DisableExploreQuery=false"
              
            ></iframe>
```

Comment: Well we also had some communications with Microsoft and some further study which clearly shows this use case of ours is really not something they support. Maybe they do not want to as it would compete with other offering of theirs.

Our next interesting option would seem to be [Microsoft Fabric](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-fabric), which at least while in preview seems to have reasonable pricing and would allow us to do both data processing and the dashboards with somewhat coherent tooling (although using PowerBI embed, still does not seem very optimal for our case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to consult with the MS product team. Since ADX employs Azure AD for authentication this method doesn't only validate the identity of the user or service principal but also ensures they possess the right permissions to access underlying data. Directly embedding ADX dashboards in non-AAD authenticated apps is complex due to ADX's inherent authentication protocols.

While retrieving the token for ADX through application authentication in the backend is viable, using this token directly in an iFrame-embedded frontend presents challenges due to Azure's intrinsic authentication checks and processes.

The iFrame goes directly to the cluster to check for authorization uses the logged in user's authentication.